# Change comment help text

Tags: feature-request

It's something I fail occasionally. When I forget on how to post a link in the comments, I usually click on the "help" button.

The text here is the following:

```
Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com)
```

I don't know why exactly, but I tend to fail here pretty often because I just read the `[link]` and write `[https://myurl](Ahh!)` - exactly the opposite way. I think another placeholder (maybe `[display-text]`) would be a good thing to overcome this?

Maybe I am just to only one who's stupid enough to fail here, I mean the documentation is correct, just the word `link` is making my brain think that I should post the link into this placeholder.

If we're already on this matter, I think a like break for each example would help increase readability and would make copying easier.